# Prometheus get the max value per bucket

Tags: prometheus, grafana, micrometer

Trying to show a graph with the max (worst) latency in each time interval (5m), using micrometer and Grafana (less relevant IMO) with Prometheus ... look into max_over_time, tried few options but numbers looks wrong or the values never go down (graph becomes flat ...)

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far so it is easier to figure out an outcome promQL query for you?

Answer (score 0):

Micrometer publishes a max gauge for every timer, you can just use and plot that (it will decay), e.g.: `http_server_requests_seconds_max` (please notice that this will have a bunch of tags you might want to query).

You can also take a look at the samples folder in Micrometer to see this in action in a simpler setup: [`LatencySample`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/samples/micrometer-samples-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/samples/LatencySample.java), [`TimerMaximumThroughputSample`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/samples/micrometer-samples-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/samples/TimerMaximumThroughputSample.java), [`TimerSample`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/samples/micrometer-samples-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/samples/TimerSample.java)